# R parallel foreach loops with spatial data

Tags: r, dataframe, parallel-processing, spatial

I have a large Spatial Lines Data Frame in R called `lines` which I want to apply the function `line2route` to from [stplanr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stplanr/index.html)

To speed up the process I wanted to break the file up into chuncks and run them in parallel.

```
library(doParallel)
batch_size <- ceiling(nrow(lines) / 6)
cl <- makeCluster(6)
registerDoParallel(cl)
    foreach(i = 1:6) %dopar% {
      l_start <- as.integer(1 + (i - 1) * batch_size)
      if(i * batch_size < nrow(lines)){
        l_fin <- as.integer(i * batch_size)
      }else{
        l_fin <- as.integer(nrow(lines))
      }
      lines_sub <- lines[c(l_start:l_fin),]
      rq <- line2route(l = lines_sub, route_fun = route_cyclestreet, plan = "quietest")
      saveRDS(rq, file = paste0("../temp/rq_batch_", i, ".Rds"))
    }
```

The code breaks up `lines` into 6 parts and runs the function, then saves the results.

This works fine in  a for loop but when I change it to a foreach loop and try to do it in parallel I get the error message

> Error in { :    task 1 failed - "c("assignment of an object of class
>   \"tbl_df\" is not valid for @'data' in an object of class
>   \"SpatialLinesDataFrame\"; is(value, \"data.frame\") is not TRUE",
>   "assignment of an object of class \"tbl\" is not valid for @'data' in
>   an object of class \"SpatialLinesDataFrame\"; is(value,
>   \"data.frame\") is not TRUE", "assignment of an object of class
>   \"data.frame\" is not valid for @'data' in an object of class
>   \"SpatialLinesDataFrame\"; is(value, \"data.frame\") is not TRUE")"

Is is possible to run a foreach loop with spatial data? I'm not worried about rejoining the data at the end as I can do that separately later.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue when I had some spatial data frame which I had used a dplyr function on e.g.:

```
sp1@data <- bind_cols(sp1@data, new_col)
```

I believe that dplyr converts the spatial dataframe (sp1@data) to a tbl_df. To solve this issue, all I had to do was:

```
sp1@data <- as.data.frame(bind_cols(sp1@data, new_col))
```

In a nutshell, you just have to ensure that all your @data's are proper data frames, not tbl_df.